# Display 9999999999 as 9-999-99999-9 in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, substr

I am trying to display a column that is in the VARCHAR format of 9999999999 as 9-999-99999-9.
I know that TO_CHAR and TO_NUMBER wont work and I know I'm suppose to use SUBSTR to do this.

I feel like I could get this done if I was able to use multiple SUBSTR functions together as one column like:

SELECT SUBSTR(column, 0, 1) - SUBSTR(column, 1, 3) etc. but that wont work either.

Any guidance is MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this in SQL instead of in your presentation layer?

Comment: "I know I'm suppose to use SUBSTR to do this." Because why? Is it a homework assignment where the you were told to use `SUBSTR` as part of the problem?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a regular expression search and replace

```
select regexp_replace('9999999999','(.)(...)(.....)(.)','\1-\2-\3-\4') from dual;
```

Comment: +1 I believe this only works on some version of oracle (e.g. 11g)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use a combination of the `SUBSTR` function and the Oracle string concatenation operator, `||`.

```
SELECT    SUBSTR(column, 1, 1)
          || '-'
          || SUBSTR(column, 2, 3)
          || '-'
          || SUBSTR(column, 4, 5)
          || '-'
          || SUBSTR(column, 9, 1)
```

Comment: That is the most unusual string concatenation operator I have encountered.

Comment: @arxanas, I completely agree.  Especially coming from a background in C#, I read this as a series of `or`s.

Answer (score 3):

I think that using `to_char` is actually the best option. It just requires a judicious use of [format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34510).

This should do it, but allow you to extend extremely easily without having to create a new query each time.

```
select replace(to_char( 999999999,'9,99,99999,9'),',','-') from dual
```

I've created a little [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40434/1) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way you can do it, by fiddling with the NLS numeric character setting:

```
select to_char(9999999999, 'fm9g999g99999g9', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.-''')
from dual;

9-999-99999-9
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(9999999999,1,1) || 
       '-' ||
       SUBSTR(9999999999,2,3) ||
       '-' ||
       SUBSTR(9999999999,4,5) ||
       '-' ||
       SUBSTR(9999999999,10,1) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose there is Phonenumber field in address table:
The query to display the date in (999)999-9999 format is as follows:

```
select concat(concat('(',substr(phone,1,3),')'),substr(phone,4,3),'-',substr(phone,7,4))
as Phone from address;
```